# laravel sharing variable between views

Tags: php, laravel

Consider this route:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    $categories = Category::all()->toHierarchy();

    $stats = array(
        'total_users' => User::all()->count(),
        'total_services' => 5,
        'total_orders' => 2,
        'latest_service' => '1 hour ago'
    );

    return View::make('homepage')
                                ->with('categories', $categories)
                                ->with('stats', $stats);
});
```

But I need $categories and $stats in all views! I don't want to repeat db calls in every view or controller, how would I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [View Composers](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#view-composers). They allow you to run some code whenever a certain view (or all views via `*`) are rendered.

```
View::composer('*', function($view){
    $categories = Category::all()->toHierarchy();

    $stats = array(
        'total_users' => User::all()->count(),
        'total_services' => 5,
        'total_orders' => 2,
        'latest_service' => '1 hour ago'
    );
    $view->with('categories', $categories)
         ->with('stats', $stats);
}
```

You can put this code in your `app/filters.php` or create a new file `app/composers.php` and include it by adding `require app_path().'/composers.php';` at the end of `app/start/global.php`

Comment: Or a service provider!

Comment: The view composer is not good for database. Let if you have included 1000 components in you view then this database query will be executed 1000 times.
Its good to use `BaseController`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple:

```
View::share('data', $data);
View::make....
```

for passing variables to all views.